# How to value count by bucket key in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I have a field `history` that stores an array of JSON objects with an ID. I want to get the top 10 IDs with a value count of the JSON objects with the specific ID.

```
"group_by_id": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "history.some_id"
      },
        "aggs": {
          "absolut": {
            "value_count": {
              "field": "history.some_id" // should count per bucket by bucket key (ID)
            }
          }
        }
    }
```

`history` field looks like this

```
{
  "some_id": 471741,
  ...
},
{
  "some_id": 471745,
  ...
},
...
```

I get these buckets and I want the `count.value` uses the `key` to filter it's result.

```
"group_by_id": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": 471741,    // count by this ID
          "doc_count": 5,
          "absolut": {
            "value": 20    // this value is not correct
          }
        },
        {
          "key": 471745,
          "doc_count": 2,
          "absolut": {
            "value": 17
          }
        },
    ...
```

My desired output are buckets that value count just the history entries with the some_id like the group by bucket key. Is that possible? Maybe you know a keyword I can find a solution with.

Answer (score 0):

I think what I tried to do is a weird workaround for my bad data design in elasticsearch. I created an own index for this and a `term` is enough achieve a toplist.